# Converting British National Grid (EPSG:7405), coordinates into latitude and longitude coordinates Using Java( JTS prefered ) programmatically

Tags: java, gis, jts

Is there a way to use the Java to convert(British National Grid (10 Figure Grid Reference),)  into lat/long?

for example, I have a   558832.516608631,180065.50201851176 and would like to generate the  lat/long using Java or JTS.

I've seen questions/solutions using Javacript, but no solutions using Java alone.

I've tried this using JTS:

```
   Coordinate c = new Coordinate(394028.93262359675,806122.3097467106);

    com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point p = gf.createPoint(c);

    CoordinateReferenceSystem utmCrs = CRS.decode("EPSG:3785");
    MathTransform mathTransform = CRS.findMathTransform(utmCrs, DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84, false);
    com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point p1 = (com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point) JTS.transform(p, mathTransform);

    System.out.println(p1.getCoordinate());
```

but the coordinates do not translate to lat/long that I could use in google maps.

Thanks.

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-os-gridref.html
contains a forumla to do this I believe, but i rather use a java lib.

here is the GeoJson Polygon I am trying to fix:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/boundaries-io/089ca86fdc88b1065f5ee3dd12af684b/raw/e9f8b54ae17d835ad8560fcb81d693201235e386/example.geojson

Attempted to use:

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem utmCrs = CRS.decode("EPSG:7405");
```

however,

```
org.opengis.referencing.operation.OperationNotFoundException: No transformation available from system "CompoundCRS[OSGB 1936 / British National Grid + ODN height]" to "GeographicCRS[WGS84(DD)]".
    at
```

The final solution was to use:

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem utmCrs = CRS.decode("EPSG:27700");
```

Comment: Please just don't down vote without a reason.

Comment: What you want is probably [Proj4j](https://trac.osgeo.org/proj4j/). Unfortunately questions asking for off site resources are explicitely off topic, so this question cannot be a good one (this is a comment without downvote to compensate the DV without comment...)

Comment: what 'off site resource' am I requesting?  I am asking how to convert to lat/long using java..perhaps geotools.

Comment: Do you think the Proj4j will be able to convert "SGB 1936 / British National Grid " to what  I need?

Comment: With the edit adding code, the question is fine for me. Unfortunately, **my** answer would be off topic for being a link only one :-). I have never used Proj4J but I used to process lot of conversions through Proj4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oups, unless I was mistaken somewhere, British National Grid is [EPSG:27700](https://epsg.io/27700). [EPSG:3785](https://epsg.io/3785) is a deprecated popular mercator projection.

But you could also have a look at [EPSG:7405](https://epsg.io/7405) which is declared as OSGB 1936 / British National Grid + ODN height. In fact I think that you want this one because you have cited SGB1936 in a comment and EPSG:7405 is OSGB 1936, while EPSG:27700 is OSBG36.

In fact, EPSG:27700 can be used without any problem on any tools because it does not depend on a specific height grid. In contrast, EPSG:7405, is more accurate because it explicitely uses the ODN height data... but requires it to be loaded in the converter tool. It can be done on a true Proj4 installation (but explaination for it is far beyond my current knowledge), and may or may not be done in Java tools. Questions about it should be asked on [Geographic Information Sytems](https://gis.stackexchange.com/). But if a 2 meter precision is acceptable, just convert from EPSG:27700 to EPSG:4326 (WGS84 lat-lon). Using the [online tool from epsg.io](https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=27700&t_srs=4326&x=394028.9326236&y=806122.3097467), your example point 394028.93262359675,806122.3097467106 is transformed in lon=-2°6'1.122", lat=57°8'45.42" in the center of Aberdeen.

Comment: updated my 'question' with the attempt to use EPSG:7405 , geotools throws an transformation error.

Comment: PostGIS also doesn't recognize any of these EPSGs (7405,3857,nor 3785)

Comment: @JerylCook: I've updated my answer explaining why ESPG 27700 would be a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this will help, because it does involve GeoTools as well as JTS, but I've used this successfully before. I don't know how all-inclusive it is in terms of the transforms it will do.

```
  public static Geometry transform(Geometry inputFeature, CoordinateReferenceSystem source, CoordinateReferenceSystem target) {
    Geometry out = null;
    try {
      final MathTransform mathTransform = CRS.findMathTransform(source, target, true);
      out = JTS.transform(inputFeature, mathTransform);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOGGER.error("Exception occurred during transform for input: " + inputFeature, e);
    }
    return out;
  }
```

Here are my imports for these objects

```
import org.geotools.coverage.grid.GridCoverage2D;
import org.geotools.coverage.grid.GridEnvelope2D;
import org.geotools.coverage.grid.GridGeometry2D;
import org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.AbstractGridFormat;
import org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.OverviewPolicy;

import org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffReader;
import org.geotools.geometry.Envelope2D;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTS;
import org.geotools.referencing.CRS;
import org.geotools.referencing.crs.DefaultGeographicCRS;
import org.jaitools.jts.CoordinateSequence2D;
import org.opengis.parameter.GeneralParameterValue;
import org.opengis.parameter.ParameterValue;
import org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem;
import org.opengis.referencing.operation.MathTransform;
```

And here are my POM entries that you'll probably need

```
       <dependency>

            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
            <version>15-RC1</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
  <artifactId>gt-geojson</artifactId>
  <version>15-RC1</version>
</dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-geotiff</artifactId>
            <version>15-RC1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-wms</artifactId>
            <version>15-RC1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Hope this helps, and I've also taken the approach of using something like PostGIS or Oracle spatial to do the transform in sql if you are already running a DB server.

UPDATE:

I think it worked for this specific case
this code:

```
 Coordinate c = new Coordinate(394028.93262359675,806122.3097467106);

      com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point p = GEOMETRY_FACTORY.createPoint(c);

      CoordinateReferenceSystem utmCrs = CRS.decode("EPSG:3785");
      Geometry transform = transform(p, utmCrs, DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
```

produced this geom (in WKT) 
POINT (3.5396221256107805 7.270235925793633)

which looks good to me (intuitively at least)

Comment: the initial coordinate data I am using is  (British National Grid (10 Figure Grid Reference) , would this work in your code?

Comment: Using 3.5396221256107805 7.270235925793633 in Google Map does not position to a valid location. 394028.93262359675,806122.3097467106   for example should be a point somewhere in the United Kingdom.   it looks like it is from a spec described here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-os-gridref.html

Comment: I also just tried using ST_Transform on this in PostGIS and no luck there either. Are you sure this coordinate is valid data?

Comment: check this out: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-os-gridref.html    try this one 651409.903, 313177.270 , in the code examples near bottom of article.

Comment: This is weird...Geotools and Oracle Spatial give the same answers. Oracle understands 7405, but geotools doesn't, however they return roughly the same location (west africa ish). PostGIS doesn't know the SRIDs. I tried the other coordinate you just posted, and that ends up near the same place (west africa  ish)

Comment: Hey, its very close..so i ran the code using EPSG:3785 for my polygon and it creates it correctly but instead of being over UK the polygon is in west africa like you mentioned.